# Calling C function with **int parameter from Fortran

Tags: c, fortran, fortran-iso-c-binding

Suppose that I have a C function with the following API :

```
int c_function(int **a);
```

How should I go about declaring a Fortran array/pointer to array, and passing it to the function, assuming that the C function is responsible for memory allocation ?

Comment: I don't think you can.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must declare a Fortan c-pointer of `type(c_ptr)`

```
type(c_ptr) :: ptr
```

then call your function (with proper interface)

```
n = c_function(ptr)
```

and only then point a Fortran array pointer there

```
real, pointer :: Array(:)

call c_f_pointer(ptr, Array, [n])
```

I assumed that `n` is the size of the array. You must know it, otherwise it is impossible.

The interface could look like

```
interface

    integer(c_int) function c_function(ptr) bind(C,name="c_function")
      use iso_c_binding
      type(c_ptr) :: ptr
    end function

end interface
```

Comment: I couldn't find an exact duplicate, just this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30481686/how-to-create-fortran-interface-for-type-void-ptr-in-code-c but that is not very good to point to. Feel free ti find better one.

Comment: Thank you, this works perfectly. Although if I'm printing the pointer in the C function, I get the same value for all the processes in my MPI communicator. But it somehow works.